# resteasy javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException: Could not find resource for full path

Tags: rest, maven, tomcat, resteasy

## Condition

1.resteasy 3.0.4.Final
2.eclipse
3.maven

## Action

I got war package into tomcat7(window x64) webapps and server run normally.
Visit http://localhost:8080/test-resteasy/rest/message/hello, and browser print "Restful example : hello".
But when I maven build tomcat7:run tomcat7-maven-plugin in eclipse,visit the same url throws:

```
 javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException: Could not find resource for full path
```

## Source (web.xml)

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

  <!-- Auto scan REST service -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- this need same with resteasy servlet url-pattern -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
        <param-value>/rest</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher
        </servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

## (pom.xml)

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>top.crowley.rest</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>resteasy Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
                <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-servlet-initializer</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>test-resteasy</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <port>8080</port>
                    <path>/test-resteasy</path>
                    <uriEncoding>UTF-8</uriEncoding>
                    <finalName>test resteasy</finalName>
                    <server>tomcat7</server>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

## MessageRestService

```
package top.crowley.resteasy;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/message")
public class MessageRestService {
    @GET
    @Path("/{param}")
    public Response printMessage(@PathParam("param") String msg) {

        String result = "Restful example : " + msg;

        return Response.status(200).entity(result).build();

    }

}
```

## Conjecture

1. I think of source code is correct, because of run war package in single tomcat 7 server successful. Maybe lack of some dependencies in `pom.xml`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Really long post to analyze each POM dependency....but why don't you give a try to compile maven in this way, suggested by official resteasy team?

`mvn clean install
mvn jetty:run`

https://github.com/resteasy/resteasy-examples/tree/3.1.1.Final/resteasy-springMVC